# Conditional Expectation Calculation

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation

I want to calculate a conditional expectation $E[U|Y=y]$ where $U$ follows a normal distribution with mean $m$ and precision $h$ (variance $1/h$), and $Y=U+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ follows a normal distribution with mean $0$ and precision $n$ (variance $1/n$). $U$ and $\epsilon$ are independent.

The answer given is $m+\frac{n}{h+n}(y-m)$ but I don't know how to get it.

I tried to plug $Y=U+\epsilon$ into the conditional expectation but don't know how to go further.

Does anyone know how and kindly help?

Thank you in advance!

**Update:**
Based on the discussion, I move steps forward.

1. In order to get the conditional expectation, I need to have the conditional density $f_{U|Y}$ first. $f_{U|Y}$ can be obtained from $\frac{f_{U,Y}}{f_Y}$, and $Y \sim N(m, \frac{1}{h}+\frac{1}{n})$, $N \sim N(m,\frac{1}{h})$.
2. $f_{U,Y}$ is, therefore, a binormal distribution $f_{U,Y} \sim N(m,m,\frac{1}{h}+\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{h},\frac{1}{h})$. The $\rho = \frac{1}{h}$ is given by the covariance between $Y$ and $U$.
3. Plug in the above parameters into the binormal formula, I get \begin{equation} 
   f_{U,Y}=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{\frac{n+h}{nh}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{h}} \sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{h})^2}} exp\{-\frac{1}{2(1-(\frac{1}{h})^2)}[\frac{(u-m)^2}{\frac{n+h}{nh}}-2\frac{1}{h}\frac{(u-m)(y-m)}{\sqrt{\frac{n+h}{nh}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{h}}}+\frac{(y-m)^2}{\frac{1}{h}}] \}
   \end{equation}

Is this expression correct? How should I proceed? It seems to me that I should also apply the condition that $Y=y$ which I have been neglected.

Comment: Have a look at the definition of the conditional expectation for continuous random variables. You will see joint density there, which you can calculate based on the densities that you are given.

Comment: @Misius Thank you for your reply! I look at the definition and first realize that I need to get the conditional density first. Do you mean that I need to calculate the conditional density according to the joint density?

Comment: @Misius I also have confusion on linking two RVs $U$ and $\epsilon$. Surely it should be done by $Y=U+\epsilon$ but I don't know how to utilize it. Would you also please give me a hint? I am new to the concept of conditional expectation and sorry for my naive question.

Comment: You can find a great number of answers here, in various levels of generality and explained with various levels of sophistication and terminology, with [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+conditional+distribution+score%3A2).  To apply most of them you will need to assume $\epsilon$ is independent of $U$ and you will need to know  that then (1) $(U,Y)$ has a Binormal distribution (also demonstrated in many threads here) and (2) how to relate precision to variance.  Which of (1) and (2) do you need help with?

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much for the useful site! I am digesting the answers. Hopefully I could figure it out by myself.

Comment: Sorry, @whuber. I searched and tried but still not able to get it done myself. Here is what I tried: 1) My final goal is to get the conditional distribution $f_{U|Y}$ and I can get it from $\frac{f_{U, Y}}{f_Y}$. 2) Since I know $Y \sim N(m, \frac{1}{h}+\frac{1}{n})$ and $U \sim N(m, \frac{1}{h})$, the closer goal is to get the joint distribution $f_{U, Y}$. It is a Binormal distribution as you pointed out. 3) I then plug all parameters into the formula (means and variances of $Y$ and $U$, and $\rho$) but then get an ugly expression and don't know how to proceed. Your help would be appreciated

Comment: And the $\rho$ I get is $1/h$.

Comment: @IANCHAN You are moving in a right direction. I would recommend you to edit your question and include what you have already done (together with the ugly expression) as it would increase the probability of other users helping you with the problem.